# Which versions of Adobe Creative Suite will work with Mavericks?

Tags: macos, compatibility, adobe

I own Adobe CS4, which works perfectly with Mountain Lion. I would like to upgrade to Mavericks, but I'm not sure if CS4 is still supported. Thus my question:

**Which versions of Adobe Creative Suite will work with Mavericks?**

Comment: Question, What does the above poster mean by "a smc reset, pram reset, and a disk repIr"? By disk replace, do they mean hard drive? What will the performance be like if this, or the two resets are not done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [this Adobe help page:](http://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/global/mac-os-mavericks-compatability.html)

> Adobe and Apple have worked closely together to test Adobe® Creative Cloud applications and Adobe Creative Suite 6 applications for reliability, performance and user experience when installed on Intel® based systems running Mac OS X Mavericks. (v10.9). All Adobe CC and CS6 products are compatible, but a few products require updates to the latest builds to work properly. Adobe Photoshop® CS5, CS4 and CS3 were also tested with Mac OS X Mavericks and there are currently no major issues known.

Answer (score 1):

It works I just upgraded to this operating system. I read the official Adobe message too. And I just decided that I am not going to wait. So I just upgraded and all of the Adobe applications work. Especially with the Video programs in CS4 it works good.

it works I was worried to until I tested it. I also recommend a smc reset, pram reset, and a disk repIr so your boot times increase because my slowed down after the installation. Just do these steps and you will be up and running.....

You can look up those things online.

Comment: Why do you ned the resets?

Answer (score 0):

About a month ago I upgraded from Leopard to Maverick and my 2008 Macbook Pro became unusable due to long response times. 2-3 minutes for just a mouse click. After many hours of tracking this down (Apple support was very patient and helpful) in the end uninstalling CS4 fixed the issue and my computer is faster than ever - probably faster because of all the clean up we did during all of this. So I've got my computer back but cannot user CS4 on it.